# Como converter "mês" para "meses", usando timestamp em PHP?

Tags: php

Eis o código:

```
function longadata($data)
{
    if(empty($data)) 
    {
        return "No date provided";
    }

    $periods         = array(_segundo, _minuto, _hora, _dia, _semana, _mes, _ano, _decada);
    $lengths         = array("60", "60", "24", "7", "4.35", "12", "10");

    $now             = time();
    $unix_date       = strtotime($data);

    if (empty($unix_date)) 
    {    
        return "Bad date";
    }

    if ($now > $unix_date) 
    {    
        $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
        $tense          = _atras;   
    } 

    else 
    {
        $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
        $tense          = _agora;
    }

    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) 
    {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }

    $difference = round($difference);

    if($difference != 1) 
    {
        $periods[$j].= "s";
    }

    return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
}
```

No HTML:

```
<li class="published-date"><?php echo longadata("2017-08-28") ?></li>
```

No resultado:

```
3 MÊSS ATRÁS
```

Quero corrigir de "mês" para "meses" por parte do código, mas tenho de manter esses códigos por causa de "segundo", "minuto", "ano", etc.:

```
if($difference != 1) 
 {
   $periods[$j].= "s";
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode verificar se a última letra é `s` ou se o `$j` é `5`:

```
if($difference !== 1){
    $periods[$j] .= mb_substr($periods[$j], -1, 1) === 's' ? 'es' : 's';
}
```

A outra forma seria:

```
if($difference !== 1){
    $periods[$j] .= $j === 5 ? 'es' : 's';
}
```

Caso exista  o acento em "mês" isso terá que ser removido, poderá simplesmente remover todos os acentos usando o `strtr`, por exemplo:

```
if($difference !== 1){
    $periods[$j] .= $j === 5 ? 'es' : 's';
    $periods[$j] = str_replace('ê', 'e', $periods[$j]);
}
```

Comment: O 3º código está óptimo, obrigado. Tenho uma dúvida. Se o site estiver em inglês ou francês? Por exemplo:

```if($difference !== 1)
{
   if ($language == "pt_BR")
   {
    $periods[$j] .= $j === 5 ? 'es' : 's';
    $periods[$j] = str_replace('ê', 'e', $periods[$j]);
   }

   if ($language == "en_GB")
   {
      $periods[$j].= "s";
   }
}
```

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o caso de função multilíngue.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi a resposta me parece ser óbvia demais, mas creio não ser isso, bom em todo caso... Nessa parte acho que você só precisa colocar um "e":

```
if($difference != 1) 
 {
   $periods[$j].= "es";
 }
```

a saida será:

```
3 _meses _atras
```

Não sei se esse era o problema, mas se não for tente explicar melhor que conseguirei te ajudar!

Comment: mas neste código, apareceu como segundoes, minutoes, ...